# How set path variable before running exe through batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
SET INCLUDE_PATH=%INCLUDE_PATH%;%3
SET LIBRARY_PATH=%LIBRARY_PATH%;%4
:: Setting dll path which is taken as 5th argument
SET PATH=%PATH%;%5  
%1 %2 /p:Configuration=%6 /p:Platform=%7 /p:PlatformToolset=%8
:: Some exe path (taken as 9th parameter) to run which needs a path of dll which i am setting at above marked line
%9
```

idealy what i am expecting

1. first Set environment variable to path
2. execute exe

what happening

1. executing exe without setting variable to PATH
2. Error for not finding dll whose path should be set in to PATH, before execution

plz help me to resolve this issue...

Comment: @JohnLBevan: If the executable is called from the batch file which does the `set`, then it will inherit that environment.

Comment: You are adding `  :: Setting dll path which is taken as 5th argument` to the end of your path. Remove that comment and it may well work. Unless that comment isn't in the actual batch file, in which case disregard this :)

Comment: this commant i have added at question posting this is not in actual batch file

Answer (score 0):

If your PATH contains some space characters, you should replace :
SET PATH=%PATH%;... by SET PATH=!PATH!;...

Comment: not work, this still showing error as prompt.when i click ok. then it compile solution file